# Starting alarm from fragment

Tags: android, fragment, alarmmanager

I want to start alarmmanager from fragment, but can't. This code work perfect in activity, but in fragment no. Any help? 
This is code from my fragment class:

```
        hour = tp1.getCurrentHour();
        minute = tp1.getCurrentMinute();

        cal.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiverActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendint = PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);

        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendint);
```

Comment: What's not working? Provide more info

Comment: Alarm doesn't start.

Comment: Solved! The problem has been in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Congrats post your answer for others to see!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the problem:

```
<activity android:name="AlarmReceiverActivity"></activity>
<activity android:name="RepeatingAlarmReceiverActivity"></activity>
```

I changed in:

```
<activity android:name="com.indyvision.test.tabswipe.fragments.AlarmReceiverActivity"></activity>
<activity android:name="com.indyvision.test.tabswipe.fragments.RepeatingAlarmReceiverActivity"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

How can the alarm go off if you are setting it to go off on the current time which will have passed once the alarm is set. Try setting it to a time in the future

Do this

```
cal.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 65);
```

Comment: hour and minute are from time Picker. and alarm time is in the future.